# Binary search using variadic templates and lambda functions

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, binary, variadic

Consider this,

```
struct Person {
    std::string name;
    Person (const std::string& n) : name(n) {}
    std::string getName(int, char) const {return name;}  // int, char play no role in this
        // simple example, but let's suppose that they are needed.
} *Bob = new Person("Bob"), *Frank = new Person("Frank"), *Mark = new Person("Mark"),
    *Tom = new Person("Tom"), *Zack = new Person("Zack");

const std::vector<Person*> people = {Bob, Frank, Mark, Tom, Zack};
```

Because `people` is sorted by name, we can carry out a binary search to find the element of `people` with a specific name.  I want the call for this to look something like

```
Person* person = binarySearch (people, "Tom",
   [](Person* p, int n, char c) {return p->getName(n,c);},
   [](const std::string& x, const std::string& y) {return x.compare(y) < 0;}, 5, 'a');
```

so the template function `binarySearch` can be used generically.  I got it working with the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

struct Person {
    std::string name;
    Person (const std::string& n) : name(n) {}
    std::string getName(int, char) const {return name;}  // int, char play no role in this
        // simple example, but let's supposes that they are needed.
} *Bob = new Person("Bob"), *Frank = new Person("Frank"), *Mark = new Person("Mark"),
    *Tom = new Person("Tom"), *Zack = new Person("Zack");

const std::vector<Person*> people = {Bob, Frank, Mark, Tom, Zack};

template <typename Container, typename Ret>
typename Container::value_type binarySearch (const Container& container, const Ret& value,
        std::function<Ret(const typename Container::value_type&, int, char)> f,
        std::function<bool(const Ret&, const Ret&)> comp,
        typename Container::difference_type low, typename Container::difference_type high,
        int n, char c) {
    if (low > high)
        std::cout << "Error!  Not found!\n";
    const typename Container::difference_type mid = (low + high) / 2;
    const Ret& r = f(container[mid], n, c);
    if (r == value)
        return container[mid];
    if (comp(r, value))
        return binarySearch (container, value, f, comp, mid + 1, high, n, c);
    return binarySearch (container, value, f, comp, low, mid - 1, n, c);
}

template <typename Container, typename Ret>
typename Container::value_type binarySearch (const Container& container, const Ret& value,
        std::function<Ret(const typename Container::value_type&, int, char)> f,
        std::function<bool(const Ret&, const Ret&)> comp, int n, char c) {
    return binarySearch (container, value, f, comp, 0, container.size() - 1, n, c);
}

int main() {
    const Person* person = binarySearch<std::vector<Person*>, std::string>
        (people, "Tom", &Person::getName,
        [](const std::string& x, const std::string& y) {return x.compare(y) < 0;}, 5, 'a');
    std::cout << person->getName(5,'a') << '\n';  // Tom
}
```

But now for reasons I don't understand, I'm not able to replace the specific arguments `int, char` with `Args...`.  You can go ahead and place `Args... args` and `args...` where needed in the above code, and it won't compile.  What is wrong here?  How to carry out this last step in the generalization? Or should the whole method be changed?

This is what I tried:

```
template <typename Container, typename Ret, typename... Args>
typename Container::value_type binarySearch (const Container& container, const Ret& value,
        std::function<Ret(const typename Container::value_type&, Args...)> f,
        std::function<bool(const Ret&, const Ret&)> comp,
        typename Container::difference_type low, typename Container::difference_type high,
        Args... args) {
    if (low > high)
        std::cout << "Error!  Not found!\n";
    const typename Container::difference_type mid = (low + high) / 2;
    const Ret& r = f(container[mid], args...);
    if (r == value)
        return container[mid];
    if (comp(r, value))
        return binarySearch (container, value, f, comp, mid + 1, high, args...);
    return binarySearch (container, value, f, comp, low, mid - 1, args...);
}

template <typename Container, typename Ret, typename... Args>
typename Container::value_type binarySearch (const Container& container, const Ret& value,
        std::function<Ret(const typename Container::value_type&, Args...)> f,
        std::function<bool(const Ret&, const Ret&)> comp, Args... args) {
    return binarySearch (container, value, f, comp, 0, container.size() - 1, args...);
}

int main() {
    const Person* person = binarySearch<std::vector<Person*>, std::string> (people, "Tom",
            &Person::getName,
        [](const std::string& x, const std::string& y) {return x.compare(y) < 0;}, 5, 'a');
    std::cout << person->getName(5,'a') << '\n';
}
```

GCC 4.9.2:

```
[Error] no matching function for call to 'binarySearch(std::vector<Person*>&, const char [4], main()::__lambda0, main()::__lambda1, int, char)'
template argument deduction/substitution failed:
[Note] 'main()::__lambda0' is not derived from 'std::function<std::basic_string<char>(Person* const&, Args ...)>'
```

**Update:**
Having studied Yakk's solution, I've adapted my solution to the following (using more first principles instead of std::equal_range):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template <typename Container, typename T, typename Comparator = std::less<T>>
typename Container::value_type binarySearchRandomAccessIterator (const Container& container, T&& value, Comparator&& compare, typename Container::difference_type low, typename Container::difference_type high) {
    if (low > high)
        {std::cout << "Error!  Not found!\n";  return container[high];}
    const typename Container::difference_type mid = (low + high) / 2;
    const auto& t = compare.function(container[mid]);  // Using 'const T& t' does not compile.
    if (t == value)
        return container[mid];
    if (compare.comparator(t, value))  // 't' is less than 'value' according to compare.comparator, so search in the top half.
        return binarySearchRandomAccessIterator (container, value, compare, mid + 1, high);
    return binarySearchRandomAccessIterator (container, value, compare, low, mid - 1);  // i.e. 'value' is less than 't' according to compare.comparator, so search in the bottom half.
}

template <typename ForwardIterator, typename T, typename Comparator = std::less<T>>
typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type binarySearchNonRandomAccessIterator (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, T&& value, Comparator&& compare) {
    ForwardIterator it;
    typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::difference_type count, step;
    count = std::distance(first, last);
    while (count > 0) {  // Binary search using iterators carried out.
        it = first;
        step = count / 2;
        std::advance(it, step);  // This is done in O(step) time since ForwardIterator is not a random-access iterator (else it is done in constant time).  But the good news is that 'step' becomes half as small with each iteration of this loop.
        const auto& t = compare.function(*it);  // Using 'const T& t' does not compile.
        if (compare.comparator(t, value)) {  // 't' is less than 'value' according to compare.comparator, so search in the top half.
            first = ++it;  // Thus first will move to one past the half-way point, and we search from there.
            count -= step + 1;  // count is decreased by half plus 1.
        }
        else  // 't' is greater than 'value' according to compare.comparator, so remain in the bottom half.
            count = step;  // 'count' and 'step' are both decreased by half.
    }
    if (compare.function(*first) != value)
        std::cout << "Error!  Not found!\n";
    return *first;
}

template <typename Container, typename T, typename Comparator = std::less<T>>  // Actually the version below could be used if Container has a random-access iterator.  It would be with the same time complexity since std::advance has O(1) time complexity for random-access iterators.
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<typename Container::iterator>::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::value, typename Container::value_type>::type
        binarySearch (const Container& container, T&& value, Comparator&& compare = {}) {
    std::cout << "Calling binarySearchWithRandomAccessIterator...\n";
    return binarySearchRandomAccessIterator (container, value, compare, 0, container.size() - 1);
}

// Overload used if Container does not have a random-access iterator.
template <typename Container, typename T, typename Comparator = std::less<T>>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<typename Container::iterator>::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::value, typename Container::value_type>::type
        binarySearch (const Container& container, T&& value, Comparator&& compare = {}) {
    std::cout << "Calling binarySearchNonRandomAccessIterator...\n";
    return binarySearchNonRandomAccessIterator (std::begin(container), std::end(container), value, compare);
}

template <typename Function, typename Comparator>
struct FunctionAndComparator {
    Function function;
    Comparator comparator;
    FunctionAndComparator (Function&& f, Comparator&& c) : function(std::forward<Function>(f)), comparator(std::forward<Comparator>(c)) {}
};

template <typename Function, typename Comparator = std::less<>>
FunctionAndComparator<std::decay_t<Function>, std::decay_t<Comparator>> functionAndComparator (Function&& f, Comparator&& c = {}) {
    return {std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Comparator>(c)};
}

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

struct Person {
    std::string name;
    Person (const std::string& n) : name(n) {}
    std::string getName (int, char) const {return name;}  // int, char play no role in this simple example, but let's supposes that they are needed.
} *Bob = new Person("Bob"), *Frank = new Person("Frank"), *Mark = new Person("Mark"), *Tom = new Person("Tom"), *Zack = new Person("Zack");

const std::vector<Person*> peopleVector = {Bob, Frank, Mark, Tom, Zack};
const std::list<Person*> peopleList = {Bob, Frank, Mark, Tom, Zack};

int main() {
    Person* tom = binarySearch (peopleVector, "Tom", functionAndComparator([](const Person* p) {return p->getName(5,'a');}, [](const std::string& x, const std::string& y) {return x.compare(y) < 0;}));
    if (tom) std::cout << tom->getName(5,'a') << " found.\n";

    Person* bob = binarySearch (peopleVector, "Bob", functionAndComparator([](const Person* p) {return p->getName(3,'k');}));  // The default comparator, std::less<std::string>, is actually the same as the comparator used above.
    if (bob) std::cout << bob->getName(3,'k') << " found.\n";

    Person* frank = binarySearch (peopleList, "Frank", functionAndComparator([](const Person* p) {return p->getName(8,'b');}));
    if (frank) std::cout << frank->getName(8,'b') << " found.\n";

    Person* zack = binarySearch (peopleList, "Zack", functionAndComparator([](const Person* p) {return p->getName(2,'c');}));
    if (zack) std::cout << zack->getName(2,'c') << " found.\n";

    Person* mark = binarySearch (peopleList, "Mark", functionAndComparator([](const Person* p) {return p->getName(6,'d');}));
    if (mark) std::cout << mark->getName(6,'d') << " found.\n";
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to accomplish.

Comment: A generic binarySearch function that accepts a container and finds the element specified by lambda functions and a value.

Comment: When you say that you can't replace int, char with Args... args, are you actually including a variadic template parameter in the function's template parameter list?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Taking a function parameter of type `std::function<something that depends on a template parameter>` is almost never what you actually want.

Comment: @T.C. agreed.  But the `identity<?>` trick in the duplicate link is also almost never what you want either.

Comment: @Yakk Yeah, not a particularly great dupe, though at least that one explains the problem :/ I'll reopen it, since we have an excellent answer that doesn't deserve to be buried under a dupehammered question :)

Comment: @T.C. added what is going wrong with the OP's code, and two simple fixes (`identity` and not using `std::function`), in addition to my "you are doing it all wrong, stop it, and do it this way!" appendix.  ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion

```
Person* person = binarySearch (people, "Tom",
  [](Person* p, int n, char c) {return p->getName(n,c);},
 [](const std::string& x, const std::string& y) {return x.compare(y) < 0;}, 5, 'a');
```

is a horrible syntax.  Your `binarySearch` function is resposible for way too many things.

But first, what went wrong: Your ambiguous error occurred because a lambda is not a `std::function`.  It tries to deduce the `std::function` type from the lambda, and fails because they are unrelated types.  The ability to deduce `Args...` from somewhere else doesn't help.

You can wrap your `std::function` arguments in:

```
template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;};
template<class Tag>using type_t=typename Tag::type;
template<class T>using identity=type_t<tag<T>>;
```

`identity< std::function< whatever... > >` and your code will start to compile (as `Args...` is deduced elsewhere).  `identity<?>` blocks template type deduction on that argument, so the compiler doesn't try anymore, and instead deduces the type from the *other* arguments.

However, this is not a good solution.

A better solution is to make the type of `f` and `c` be `F` and `C` -- don't make them into `std::function`s at all.  This removes pointless type-erasure overhead, and removes the need for `identity<?>`

This is still not a good solution, because your template function does a bunch of things, few of them well.  Instead, decompose your operation into simpler problems, then compose those together:

---

First, we already have `std::equal_range`, which is going to be a better binary search than any you are likely to write.  Writing a function that returns a single element, and takes a container, seems reasonable, as working with iterators is annoying.

To pull this off, first we write some range-based boilerplate:

```
namespace adl_aux {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  template<class R>
  auto adl_begin(R&&)->decltype(begin(std::declval<R>()));
  template<class R>
  auto adl_end(R&&)->decltype(end(std::declval<R>()));
}
template<class R>
using adl_begin = decltype(adl_aux::adl_begin(std::declval<R>));
template<class R>
using adl_end = decltype(adl_aux::adl_end(std::declval<R>));

template<class R>using iterator_t = adl_begin<R>;
template<class R>using value_t = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::declval<iterator_t<R>>())>;
```

This allows us to support `std::` containers and arrays and 3rd party iterable containers and ranges.  The `adl_` stuff does argument dependent lookup of `begin` and `end` for us.  The `iterator_t` and `value_t` does SFINAE-friendly determining of the value and iterator type of a range.

Now, `bin_search` on top of that boilerplate:

```
template<class R, class T, class F=std::less<T>>
value_t<R>* bin_search( R&& r, T&& t, F&& f={} ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  auto range = std::equal_range( begin(r), end(r), std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<F>(f) );
  if (range.first==range.second) return nullptr;
  return std::addressof( *range.first ); // in case someone overloaded `&`
}
```

which returns a pointer to the element `t` under the ordering `f` presuming `R` is sorted under it if it exists, and otherwise `nullptr`.

The next part is your ordering mess:

```
[](Person* p, int n, char c) {return p->getName(n,c);},
[](const std::string& x, const std::string& y) {return x.compare(y) < 0;}, 5, 'a'
```

first, get rid of that `args...`:

```
[](int n, char c){
  return [n,c](Person* p) {return p->getName(n,c);}
}(5,'a'),
[](const std::string& x, const std::string& y) {return x.compare(y) < 0;}
```

if you really need to do it on one line, do the binding directly.

Next, we want `order_by`:

```
template<class F, class C>
struct order_by_t : private F, private C {
  F const& f() const { return *this; }
  C const& c() const { return *this; }
  template<class T>
  auto f(T&&t)const
  ->decltype( std::declval<F const&>()(std::declval<T>()) )
  {
    return f()(std::forward<T>(t));
  }
  template<class T, class... Unused> // Unused to force lower priority
  auto f(T&&t, Unused&&... ) const
  -> std::decay_t<T>
  { return std::forward<T>(t); }
  template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  bool operator()(Lhs&& lhs, Rhs&& rhs) const {
    return c()( f(std::forward<Lhs>(lhs)), f(std::forward<Rhs>(rhs)) );
  }
  template<class F0, class C0>
  order_by_t( F0&& f_, C0&& c_ ):
    F(std::forward<F0>(f_)), C(std::forward<C0>(c_))
  {}
};
template<class C=std::less<>, class F>
auto order_by( F&& f, C&& c={} )
-> order_by_t<std::decay_t<F>, std::decay_t<C>>
{ return {std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<C>(c)}; }
```

`order_by` takes a projection from a domain to a range, and optionally an ordering on that range, and produces an ordering on the domain.

```
order_by(
  [](int n, char c){
    return [n,c](Person const* p)
    ->decltype(p->getName(n,c)) // SFINAE enabled
    {return p->getName(n,c);};
  }(5,'a'),
  [](const std::string& x, const std::string& y) {return x.compare(y) < 0;}
}
```

is now an ordering on `Person const*`s that follows your requirements.

We then feed this into `bin_search`:

```
auto ordering = order_by(
  [](int n, char c){
    return [n,c](Person const* p)
    ->decltype(p->getName(n,c)) // SFINAE enabled
    {return p->getName(n,c);}
  }(5,'a'),
  [](const std::string& x, const std::string& y) {return x.compare(y) < 0;}
);
Person*const* p = bin_search( people, "Tom", ordering );
```

now, some care had to be made to make `order_by` a "transparent" function object, where it accepts both things that can be projected (under the projection) and cannot be (which are passed directly to the comparator).

This requires that the projection operation be SFINAE friendly (ie, that it "fail early").  To this end, I explicitly determined its return type.  (Below we see that this is not required, but it may be in more complex situations).

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/759e5dc7c650c441).

Amusingly, your `[](const std::string& x, const std::string& y) {return x.compare(y) < 0;}` agrees with `operator<` on a `std::string`, so you could drop that (and make `order_by` simpler).  However, I suspect your real use case needs it, and it is a useful feature to fortify `order_by` with.

Finally, note that this part:

```
  [](int n, char c){
    return [n,c](Person const* p)
    ->decltype(p->getName(n,c)) // SFINAE enabled
    {return p->getName(n,c);}
  }(5,'a'),
```

is ugly, and can be replaced with:

```
  [](Person const* p)
    ->decltype(p->getName(5,'a')) // SFINAE enabled
    {return p->getName(5,'a');}
```

which is less ugly.  Also, because the parameter check of the lambda is enough, we can drop the SFINAE explicit return type stuff:

```
  [](Person const* p)
    {return p->getName(5,'a');}
```

and we are done.  [Simpler example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1742c4e17a8ce84f):

```
auto ordering = order_by(
   [](Person const* p)
     {return p->getName(5,'a');}
);
Person*const* p = bin_search( people, "Tom", ordering );
```

or even:

```
Person*const* p = bin_search( people, "Tom",
  order_by( [](Person const* p) {return p->getName(5,'a');} )
);
```

which looks far less ugly, no?

Oh, and:

```
using std::literals;
Person*const* p = bin_search( people, "Tom"s,
  order_by( [](Person const* p) {return p->getName(5,'a');} )
);
```

might have better performance, as it will avoid repeatedly constructing a `std::string("Tom")` on every comparison.  Similarly, a `getName` that returns a `std::string const&` (if possible) can also give a performance boost.  The "projection lambda" might have to have a `->decltype(auto)` in it to realise this second boost.

I used some C++14 above.  The `std::remove_reference_t<?>` (and similar) aliases can be replaced with `typename std::remove_reference<?>::type`, or you can write your own `_t` aliases.  The advice to use `decltype(auto)` can be replaced with `decltype(the return expression)` in C++11.

`order_by_t` uses inheritance to store `F` and `C` because they are likely to be empty classes, so I wanted to exploit the empty base optimization.